# C++ upper_bound no matching function call to object of type <lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I am newbie in C++ and I am trying to use lower_bound and upper_bound for sorting and searching vector. This line of code make strange error for me:

```
up = upper_bound(low, this->data.end(), name, [](const human & a, const string & b) {return (a.name < b) ? true : false;});
```

The error is no matching function call to object of type `<lambda at ...` which is not fired on this line, but in algorithm library on line 4104. I am confused, because I am using `upper_bound` in another part of code it works fine. Also when I changed the function from `upper_bound` to `lower_bound` everything works fine.

Does anyone has idea how to solve that?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the full compiler error and use the code formatting button to format your code.

Comment: Unrelated, but remember that the expression `a.name < b` already is a boolean `true` or `false`, so no need for the ternary condition.

Comment: this link will help you out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268848/c-lambdas-for-stdsort-and-stdlower-bound-equal-range-on-a-struct-element-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using mixed type comparisons you need to be rather careful which argument goes where. According to the standard (25.4.3.2 [upper.bound] paragraphs 1 and 2), the comparisons done are `comp(value, *it)` where `value` is the third argument to `std::upper_bound()`. You don't show enough code but based on the signature I'd guess you need to change the order of the arguments. Using the following lambda should work:

```
[](std::string const& name, human const& object) {
    return name < object.name;
};
```

It is worth noting that `std::lower_bound()` expects the arguments in the opposite order (25.4.3.1 [lower.bound] paragraphs 1 and 2). That the lambda you have, indeed, should work for `std::lower_bound()`!

Comment: Instead of using mixed type comparisons, I recommend using [std::partition_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. I split the arguments and everything works fine. Sorry about just one line of the code, but this is homework to school and we can't show our solutions on web.

Comment: It is entirely viable to create an excerpt showing the problem! I tested my solution with ~15 lines of code (including all headers, line breaks, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that inside the body of the algorithm there is used the following expression

```
!Predicate( value, *iterator )
```

As your class has no conversion function that would convert an object of type std::string to an object of type humen or from an object of type type human to an object of type std::string then the compiler issue the error.