# Using comparison operators to sort string array

Tags: c++, arrays

I looked everywhere and I could not find a concrete answer that suits my needs. I want use this type of format to sort a more complicated array than this example. It compiles, but when I run it I get the `terminated by signal SIGSEV` (address boundary error).

A simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
string array[] = {zipper, bad, dog, apple, car};
string temparray[5];
int counter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
       for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            if(array[i] > array[x]){
              counter++;
            }
        }
       temparray[counter] = array[i];
}

for(int y = 0; y < 5; y++){
       array[y] = temparray[y];   
}
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: `temparray[counter]` with `counter >= 5`. you may have wanted `int counter = 0;` in the first loop.

Comment: `counter` will be 5 or greater, I would guess. Run the program under `gdb` or whatever to debug.

Comment: Jarod42 you where spot on seeing that counter was supposed to be inside the first for loop so it resets with every iteration. thank you very much

Comment: This is probably an exercise, but in real world you should seriously use `std::vector` and `std::sort`. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2758095/620382)

Answer (score 0):

You never reset `counter`. Suppose that your array is `{5,4,3,2,1}`. Then after the first iteration of the `for` loop, you'd have `counter`=4. After the next iteration of the inner for loop, `counter` would be 7, and you'd be trying to access the 7th element in `temparray` on your line

```
temparray[counter] = array[i];
```

but `temparray` is only 5 elements long. I don't offhand know how the `>` and `<` operators work for `std::string`'s, but I'd bet oaks to acorns this is your problem.

You can fix this just by adding

```
counter=0;
```

directly after the aforementioned line:

```
temparray[counter] = array[i];
```

or by initializing it to zero at the start of the loop, or declaring it in the loop or what have you.